# Is there anyway to auto start the unix based system after shutdown?

Tags: shell, unix, tomcat

My Local server got shutdown because of power off. Is there any way to autostart the system as well as apache tomcat also.

Comment: Please update your Q to indicate if  the power to your server is restored. Or is the server completely off, requiring someone/something to activate the power switch? Good luck.

Comment: Use the remote management console of your server or send a magic packet for WoL.

Comment: @Michael-O - what is a `magic packet for WoL` ??

Comment: @Coffee Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You may look into [Apache Daemon](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/) , this is useful tool for such activities

> Jsvc is a set of libraries and applications for making Java
>   applications run on UNIX more easily.  Jsvc allows the application
>   (e.g. Tomcat) to perform some privileged operations as root (e.g. bind
>   to a port < 1024), and then switch identity to a non-privileged user.

[See here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html)

[Also see - Running Tomcat as a service on Linux](https://freddyandersen.wordpress.com/2009/09/02/running-tomcat-as-a-service-on-linux/)